# I have added the rigid body modification but the problem occurs when the animation starts, why?

Tags: physics, dynamic

I have created a pulley system that would fall when more mass is added but when the animation starts it flies off in another direction other than just falling down.
How do I fix this problem?

[image: Pulley system]

[image: After Animation starts]

This is the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2uf7g523efpaxr04tujpq/rub_goldberg_assingment.blend?rlkey=703sme1asl31e0fhp0ery4cyd&dl=0

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It is in the description above.

Comment: it looks like the previous problem, it doesn't look like the images you show

Comment: The scaling problem? I have tried applying scale to all of the objects and I changed it slightly because I was trying to use the animation keyframes until they were no longer needed once the dominos fell on the platform. but before it would fly off in another direction just like in the beginning.

Comment: As @moonboots says, that's the wrong Blend file. There's no pulley system in that file.

Comment: I apologize for that I updated the link to the correct file but it was larger than 30 mb so I had to use dropbox, I hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

1. rope has a Y position driver dependent on "Cube" Z-location; 2) "Cube" (CubeAction.002) has no Z-location animation. Not sure how this could work as is. 3) If I set location keyframes on "Cube" z-loc, all works well, both in setting the keyframes and during playback.

Also note how I could use blend-exchange by reducing the objects down to the essential ones around the question/problem area....

[image]